# How can I delete my info from Apple TV first generation storage

Tags: appletv

I have no use for my Apple TV A1218 first gen and want to delete any personal information, movies, etc stored on it. However when I connect it to my tv nothing happens.

Comment: You want to do a factory reset in settings. Sounds like your first issue is successfully plugging it into your tv, selecting the proper input, and having it display on your tv - right? Did you try switching inputs, replugging it in etc?

Comment: You're going to have to qualify what you mean by "nothing happens".